# A graph G has V vertices, each of degree 9. It also has 54 edges. What is V?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm a bit lost as to how to do this. Without knowing the number of vertices it is impossible to draw a picture, however, I suspect that there is a formulaic way to solve this. My initial assumption was to divide the number of edges by the degree of each vertex, but that does not account for repeat counting. Any advice / help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{n \cdot 9}{2} = 54$$

implies $n = 12$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The number of edges of a graph $G$ with $V=(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ s.t. each vertex $v_i$ has degree $d_i$ is given by $ \frac12\sum_{i}d_i = |E|$. In your case, the number of edges is 54 and $d_i=9$ for all $i$.

Comment: This made the problem a little clearer thank you

Answer (score 2):

By the hand-shaking lemma, the number $m$ of edges satisfies $2m=\sum_{v \in V} d_G(v)$.

Now $d_G(v)=9$ for each vertex $v$, so here the number $m$ of edges satisfies $2m = 9|V|$. Now $m=54$ so $2m=108$.

Can you finish from here.

Comment: Thank you for this... I can sort of follow but the notation is a bit outside of my ability to comprehend.